# If radio is checked on submit jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, django

im trying to check if a radio button is checked on submit of a form. Ive researched but i didnt get it to work. It might be a silly mistake or type but ive been trying for hours now. The two different methods i tried are.

```
  $("#form").submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#radio").attr("checked") == "checked") {
      alert("checked");
    }
    if ($("#radio").is("checked")) {
      alert("checked");
    }
  });
```

And the html is:

```
  <form action="" method="POST" id="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="" id="radio" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Im doing this in django also. Thanks for any replies and sorry if im just making a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first `if` condition you need to use `prop()` to check the `checked` property of the element object. Using `attr()` reads the `checked` attribute from the DOM, which is not changed as the user interacts with the radio button.

In the second `if` condition you need to use the `:checked` psuedo-selector with the `is()` method; note the leading `:` here.

```js
$("#form").submit((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($("#radio").prop("checked")) {
    console.log("checked");
  }

  if ($("#radio").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
  <label for="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="" id="radio" />
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```